# Name of vertical pipe as in a|b

Tags: syntax

What is `|` called?  `Or` is something different.  In particular, I want to imitate

```
Cases[stuff,a|b]
```

with something like

```
Cases[stuff,CaseOr@@{a,b}]
```

Succinct ways to match any element of a list (as is the goal in this `Cases`) would be useful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alternatives` as in

```
Cases[{1,2,3},Alternatives@@{1,2}]
```

Little embarrassed about this one... glad I found the answer though!